# Conjecture: Partitioning $\Bbb N$ into parts that sum to $13^i$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, set-partition

Recently I was thinking and came up with a conjecture that goes as follows:

> **Conjecture:**
>
> There exists a $\Omega$ such that
> $$\Omega = \Bigg\{A_i \ \Bigg| \ \forall i,j:i\not=j, \ A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset , \ \bigcup_{i} A_i=\Bbb N:\sum_{k\in A_i} k=13^i \Bigg\}$$
> where $0\not \in \Bbb N$

Comment: Your notation has problems. When you write $\exists \Omega:\Omega=\{\cdots\}$, it means that "there exists $\Omega$ which is equal to the set defined on the right-hand side", and this is trivial: Simply define $\Omega$ as the set on the right-hand side. But then your definition of $\Omega$ does not make sense: what is $A_i$? where does $i$ range from? I think you mean that you conjecture that there exists a collection $\Omega$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with certain properties, but I'll let you try to explain it by yourself.

Comment: Why not write the far clearer sentence *"there exists a partition $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup A_i$ for which the sum of the elements of $A_i$ is $13^i$"*?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it inductively in the "naive" way: Set $A_1=\{1,12\}$, $A_2=\{2,13^2-2\}$,$\ldots$, $A_{11}=\{11,13^{11}-11\}$, $A_{12}=\{13,13^{13}-13\}$, $A_{13}=\{14,13^{14}-13\}$,...

You have, however, to show that this sequence satisfies the properties you want. I think one elementary way to do it is the following: We want to define $A_i$ inductively with the properties

1. $A_i$ has two elements;
2. $\sum_{k\in A_i}k=13^i$;
3. The $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint;
4. $\{1,\ldots,n\}\subseteq A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$.

Define $A_1=\{1,12\}$. Given $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ satifying the three properties above, let $k=\min(\mathbb{N}\setminus(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n))$, and define $A_{n+1}=\{k,13^{n+1}-k\}$. Properties 1.,2. and 4. are immediate. As for property 3., we need to show that $13^{n+1}-k$ does not belong to some $A_i$, $i\leq n$. Since each $A_i$ has two elements, $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ has at most the $2n$ first elements of $\mathbb{N}$, so $k\leq 2n$. But then $13^{n+1}-k\geq 13^{n+1}-2n>13^n\geq 13^i$ for all $i\leq n$, so property 2. implies $13^{n+1}-k\not\in A_i$< as desired.